# List of List turn 90 degrees in haskell

Tags: haskell

Say I have a list of lists of a type: can I rotate it (in a sense) so that:

```
[[a,b],    [[b,d],
 [c,d]] =>  [a,c]]
```

For any size list? Or if not possible for arbitrary sized list just for a list of size 6x6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should give you the desired output:

```
import Data.List (transpose)

rotate :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
rotate = reverse . transpose
```

Testing:

```
*Main> rotate [[1,2],[3,4]]
[[2,4],[1,3]]
*Main> rotate [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[[3,6,9],[2,5,8],[1,4,7]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just Hoogle it!

[`[[a]] -> [[a]]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D)

Comment: Only problem, transpose doesn't quite do what I need! I need a strict rotation...

Comment: by rotating you mean like shifting? What you expect as result for 3 x 3?

Comment: @jQwierdy Aha! I was having a lot of trouble reading your example before Jon Purdy's edit, and the result is that this is bad advice. Apologies.